# Would the word "dehumidifier" be another word for "heater"?

Tags: meaning

A salesman told me that they do not call heater (not water heater that you use in bathroom but it is the one that warm up the air around) a heater. They call it `dehumidifier`.

Anyone kind enough to tell me whether the word `heater` can be called `dehumidifier`?

Comment: All said, it may not be fair to call the salesman a liar, as such. He could have chosen his pitch carefully to mean that his dehum serves you the same purpose as a heater, in which case, he is technically correct. Think air-cooler in reverse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. They do completely different things.

A dehumidifier reduces the moisture in the air.

A heater raises the temperature of the air.

Comment: Marked as answer - very organized & clear cut executive summary.

Comment: +1 In the summer, a dehumidifier has the effect of making you feel *cooler*.  In the winter I don't know if it has that effect, but it sure doesn't have the opposite effect.  So not only is it not a heater, but it doesn't even help you feel heated.

Comment: In practice a closed loop dehumidifier must also warm the place up, but if it is well designed a small fraction of it's power draw is converted to heat and the rest goes to condensing the  water vapor.

Comment: @dmckee: It necessarily converts 100% of its power draw to heat, but hopefully takes out a lot of moisture with that power.

Comment: @Charles is correct. All the energy used by an appliance ends up as waste heat.

Comment: Reduced humidity would make you **feel** cooler, summer or winter.

Comment: @Gapton, Hi Gapton, don't really get what you mean - summer is suppose to be hot but how could you feel cooler - can teach me how?

Comment: @LarryMorries I feel that its getting off topic but go to Wikipedia and look up "Relative Humidity" and there is a paragraph : For example, if the air temperature is 24 °C (75 °F) and the relative humidity is zero percent, then the air temperature feels like 21 °C (69 °F). If the relative humidity is 100 percent at the same air temperature, then it feels like 27 °C (80 °F). [End of quote] If water evaporates quicker when we sweat we are cooled quicker, dry air also gives a cooling sensation.

Answer (score 3):

No. The primary job of a dehumidifier is to remove the moisture vapour (humidity) from the air and not to heat the air.

Comment: +1 For explaining and answering `No` - Now, I know that the Salesman is actually lying.

Comment: @Larry Morries Well, you can have a humidifier and a heater in one appliance.  Nothing stopping that from happening.

Answer (score 3):

The word *dehumidifier* does not have the same meaning as the word *heater*.

Now, practically speaking, a typical dehumidifier does not significantly heat the room. It transfers heat from the air into itself, which cools the air and causes condensation. Then it transfers the heat back into the cold air and recirculates it. The net heating is zero – except that any electrical appliance, even a light bulb, creates some waste heat in its operation, and will cause its environment to be *slightly* warmer.

Suggest this question be moved to [DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) which is a better place to get answers to questions about home appliances.

Comment: +1 For the clear explanation to describe that there is differences between the two term.

Comment: Actually asking in here cause I am looking for differences & meaning between the two term.

Comment: For a dehumidifier, the amount of waste heat could be significant, and warm the area more than slightly.

Comment: A $178 Frigidaire 30 pint dehumidifier is rated at 390 watts. So the amount of waste heat is equivalent to several bright incandescent lightbulbs. A small Crane flat panel space heater is rated at 1500 watts but costs only $49 and does not need to be emptied periodically. (Prices courtesy of Lowe's.) So the waste heat from a dehumidifier is comparable to the waste heat from the vanity lights in the bathroom, but can't compete with an actual heater.

Comment: @MetaEd: So that dehumidifier gives off about a quarter of the heating of the space heater, while the vanity lights (if they're like the three in my bathroom) are about 1/40th.

Comment: I was comparing the dehumidifier to the waste heat from the vanity lights. My master bath vanity lights have ten 25W clear incandescent bulbs so the waste heat is about 2/3 the dehumidifier. If you have three 60W lamps, the waste heat is about 1/2. (Of course the smart thing is to switch to CFLs or LEDs. If you've switched to 14W CFLs, then you're at about 1/9. I will be trying to talk my wife into 4W LEDs the next time I replace one, which will put me at about 1/10 when we get them all done.)